# How Upper Riemann Sum is well defined?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

The upper Riemann sum is defined as
$$U(f;P)=\sum_{k=1}^n \mid I_k \mid \sup_{x \in I_k}f(x)$$
where $f$ is a real valued function on interval $I = [a, b]$ and $P$ is partition of interval $I = [a, b]$
$$ P= \{x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,...,x_n\}$$ $I_k = [x_{k-1},x_k]$. Normally, to show a function is well defined we take two equal input and map gives equal output.Here we have $ f $ and $P$ are combined input. How can we show that Upper Riemann Sum is a well defined function?

Comment: You have a typo. The URS should be $\sum_{k}\left|I_{k}\right|\sup_{x\in I_{k}}f(x)$.

Comment: typos are fixed @parsiad

Comment: Convince yourself that the supremum of a set is well-defined in your sense. The rest follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an input can be represented in multiple equivalent ways, then we have a concern of whether each representation would give us the same output. Also, we want to check each step can be computed such as we do not encounter scenario such as $\infty - \infty$ or work with an infinite sum that does not converge.

In this context, $P$ is specified, hence we can construct $I_k$ without ambiguity and of course $0 < |I_k|< \infty$.

Also, $f$ is given, again, we can compute $\sup_{x \in I_k}f(x)$ even though it can be $\infty$. Note that it can't be $-\infty$.

We then just have to multiply $|I_k|$ and $\sup_{x \in I_k} f(x)$ and compute the summation finitely many times. We won't encounter the scenario of  summing up $\infty$ and $-\infty$,

Comment: how can we check if the input is represented in different ways and it will give the same output? (First point)

Comment: can a function be represented in a different way? we just define a rule, the domain, and the codomain right, and the function if fully specified right?

Comment: You mean if a function whose domain and codomain are given. Then we just check that the values of the function fall into the codomain. We do not take two different input and check function has equal outputs in the case where domain and codomain are given.

Comment: [well-definedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-defined) is about computing things without ambiguity.  I don't see the source of ambiguity.